# Reporting Services Report against ObjectDataSource in a separate application library

Tags: reporting-services, domain-driven-design

Rather than generate my RS reports by directly accessing a SQL database, I'd like to take advantage of Domain Objects I've already written in another application, where complex business rules and calculations already exist so that I don't have to duplicate that logic in stored procedures and other code. I want to keep it DRY.

It would be nice to treat the reporting concern as just another type of view

Is that possible with Reporting Services? It seems logical that it should be, but I'm not finding much information out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  You can use the ReportViewer control in Local Processing mode.  In this mode, you can just pass a DataSource instead of directly accessing the Database.

Keep in mind that there are certain things that you cannot do in LocalMode that you can in ServerMode.  One that I recall, is exporting to anything other than PDF or Excel.